# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 using Cocoa Pods

Tags: ios, xcode, device, cocoapods, armv7

Have some trouble which makes me crazy for a long time. I'm using pods in my project. When I run on simulator, everything ok. Project builds and runs without errors. But when I try to run on my device I get errors like

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ITGShareMenu.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBLoginView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ITGShareMenu.o
```

[image]

Why on simulator project launchs with no errors but on device it crashes? How can I fix it?
Thanks for yours appropriate answers!

Comment: What device? What iOS? Did you try to create another Architecture only adding armv7 and then in other line armv7s?

Comment: Fabio, I try to run on iPad 3, on iPhone 4s, ios 8.0.
I'll try to create another architecture and comment here in 15-20 minutes. Thanks:)

Comment: @Fabio, I'm tryed to create another architecture, but the same error:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, at least I've fought it! I deleted pods and reinstalled them. Afterwards I got errors like libs for test target not included in resources. I've cloned test target, deleted first test target and got app on my device! Uhu!:)